# Mono httpwebrequest turns wifi off

Tags: android, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an Mono/Android app with a background service that makes some call to a rest webservice via httpwebrequest. On some devices (a samsung galaxy s4 and s4 mini) the requests begins to hang, then timeout and after some minutes the wifi of the phone is turned off (I suggest is the OS) .
Closing the app the wifi returns available, anybody knows why?

Comment: this sounds like a bug, which you should report in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally, found.  It seems to be a strange problem with some Samsung Devices and the wpa2-psk encription of Wi-fi.
The same device (with the same app) attached on a WEP works like a clock.

It's definitively a samsung bug.